# search problems with Oracle.DataAccess 2.121.2.0 / Oracle 12 client when change the table structure must be reboot iis

Tags: asp.net, oracle, odp.net

i have some problems with  use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.

i use this dll  to seach a table,  the result is ok.  After the table field changes ( for example  to  add a field  or change field type)  then  the search is error.

this is case:
asp.net code;

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using System.Data;  
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;  


public partial class ptest : System.Web.UI.Page  
{  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
    }  
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(Common.connstr))  
        {  
            connection.Open();  
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from v_tmp ", connection);  
            OracleDataAdapter sa = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
            sa.Fill(dt);  
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();  
            Response.Write(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());  
        }   
    }  
}
```

the view v_tmp code

```
create or replace  view v_tmp as  
select 1 a,2 b from dual
```

first run is ok , when i change the view v_tmp,   add field  or change field  then display error 。 must reboot iis then ok.
for example

```
create or replace  view v_tmp as  
select 1 a,2 b ,1 c from dual  

create or replace  view v_tmp as  
select sysdate a,2 b from dual
```

the error display

```
[Exception: Internal Error]  
  OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean bAllInputBinds, Int32 arrayBindCount, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]& rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean& bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, List`1& implicitRSList, Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired) +3285  
  OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF) +14144  
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior) +2978  
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +344  
  System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +108  
  ptest.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\job\MobileSupport4.0\Web\ptest.aspx.cs:24  
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692746  
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108  
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12  
  System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15  
  System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35  
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562
```

this is the bug  or the use Configuration issues, if it is how the configuration changes.

Comment: OMG!!! I had the same problema, but at least restarting IIS solved it. Thanks for reporting.